# How to set scope of form button using javascript and not HTML 5

Tags: javascript, forms

So in HTML 5, you can set buttons outside of a form to point to that form by using the `form` attribute.  Is there a way to do this in Javascript?  I need all references to `this.form` to point to a form somewhere else on the page.  I've already tried:

```
<input type="button" onclick="this.form = document.forms['MyForm']; this.form.name.value = 'Blah' />
```

But with no success.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you want to the button to submit the desired form, you can simply submit on click.

Comment: You can't assign to `this`. is `documents.forms['MyForm'].name.value = 'Blah'` really out of the question?

Comment: I think you'll have less trouble syntactically if you just use a jquery selector

Comment: @Angelo: he isn't assigning to `this`.  He's trying to assign to `this.form`, where `this` would be the `input` element and `form` would be a property on that element.  It's perfectly fine.

Comment: *sigh* I should read ...gooder... >>

Comment: Actually firefox says "setting a property that has only a getter" when trying to put something in "this.form". Besides there's a missing double quote at the end of the onclick handler :)

Comment: I can't just set it using the `documents.forms['MyForm'].name.value = 'Blah'` (I already tried) because there are other functions that get called by the `onclick` event, and those functions also refer to `this.form`.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your form elements should have a unique ID, so you can change the value of the element without referencing the form, like this:

```
document.getElementById('your_field_id').value = 'Blah';
```

To submit the form, use document.forms:

```
document.forms['MyForm'].submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm()" />

function submitForm() {
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What about something like this using jquery?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="test" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="button" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#button").click(function(){
                $("#test").val("Hello World!");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is nothing that indicates jQuery is an option here